# Store multiple xml node into list and show in MVC view

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-xml

I will like to store multiple xml linq result into a list and show in mvc view but it stores null value when debugging. Anyway to store it in the List?
Thanks!

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult SURV_Answer_Result(int Survey_ID, string Language = "ENG")
{
List<AnswerQuestionViewModel> viewmodel = new List<AnswerQuestionViewModel>();

            var query = from r in db.SURV_Question_Ext_Model
                        join s in db.SURV_Question_Model
                        on r.Qext_Question_ID equals
                        s.Question_ID
                        select new { r, s };

            var viewModel = new AnswerQuestionViewModel();
            viewModel.Survey_ID = Survey_ID;

            List<string> AnsResult = new List<string>();

            foreach (var item in query.ToList())
            {

                string str = item.s.Answer_Data;
                XElement qconfig;
                qconfig = XElement.Parse(str);

                string value = item.s.Question_Type;
                int i = 0;

                switch (value)
                {

                    case "Single_Line":
                        {

                                XElement SingleLineAns =
                                (from node in qconfig.Elements("Answer")
                                select node).SingleOrDefault();

       Unable to store=====>    viewModel.ResultAnswer = SingleLineAns.Value;       
                                AnsResult.Add(viewModel.ResultAnswer[i]);
                                i++;

                        }
                        break;

                    case "Multiple_Line":
                        {
                           // do nothing
                        }
                        break;



                viewmodel.Add(new AnswerQuestionViewModel()
                {              
                    ResultAnswer = viewModel.ResultAnswer        
                });
            }

            return View(viewmodel);
        }
}
```

My AnswerQuestionModel:

```
public string[] ResultAnswer { get; set; }
```

My View:

```
@model List<SurveyTool.Models.AnswerQuestionViewModel>
    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
       @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].ResultAnswer[i])
    }
```

XML Answer Data Sample (will get 'ssd' after extract):

```
<!--Question Configuration--><AnswerData><Answer>ssd</Answer></AnswerData>
```

Comment: public string[] ResultAnswer { get; set; } shouldn't be? public List<string>ResultAnswer { get; set; } and then viewModel.ResultAnswer = SingleLineAns.Value;  change to  viewModel.ResultAnswer = new List<string>();viewModel.ResultAnswer .Add(SingleLineAns.Value);

Comment: @DanielGpeReyes thanks and it works! Really appreciate it! Please add as answer, i will marked it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
      public string[] ResultAnswer { get; set; }
```

to

```
     public List<string>ResultAnswer { get; set; }
```

and then

```
     viewModel.ResultAnswer = SingleLineAns.Value;
```

change to

```
     viewModel.ResultAnswer = new List<string>();
     viewModel.ResultAnswer .Add(SingleLineAns.Value);
```